# Error while building React Native app for Android - Execution failed for task ':react-native-async-storage_async-storage:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'

Tags: android, react-native, gradle, build-error

I am developing a React Native application on a Mac and trying to build it for Android. However, when I run npm run android to launch the app on my phone, I encounter the following error:

```
BUILD FAILED in 3s
error Failed to install the app. Command failed with exit code 1: ./gradlew app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':react-native-async-storage_async-storage:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':react-native-async-storage_async-storage:androidJdkImage'.
> Failed to transform core-for-system-modules.jar to match attributes {artifactType=_internal_android_jdk_image, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
> Execution failed for JdkImageTransform: /Users/marc-antoineleonelli/Library/Android/sdk/platforms/android-34/core-for-system-modules.jar.
> Error while executing process /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/zulu-21.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/jlink with arguments {--module-path /Users/marc-antoineleonelli/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/7056ed491d13671bf4afd0abdfd4273b/transformed/output/temp/jmod --add-modules java.base --output /Users/marc-antoineleonelli/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/7056ed491d13671bf4afd0abdfd4273b/transformed/output/jdkImage --disable-plugin system-modules}
I am experiencing the same error for several other libraries, not just the one mentioned above.
```

Here is my build.gradle file:

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "34.0.0"
        minSdkVersion = 21
        compileSdkVersion = 34
        targetSdkVersion = 34
        ndkVersion = "25.1.8937393"
        kotlinVersion = "1.8.0"
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle")
        classpath("com.facebook.react:react-native-gradle-plugin")
        classpath("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin")
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
        maven {
            url("https://maven.google.com")
        }
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
    }
}

apply plugin: "com.facebook.react.rootproject"
```

I use react-native 0.73.5 and Gradle 8.3.

I tried several solutions to resolve the issue, including trying different libraries, deleting the cache, running a clean on gradlew, and updating the Android SDK to the latest version.

I would appreciate any help in resolving this issue. Thank you!

Comment: can you please share react-native & gradlew version?
also tell me when you got this problem? after installing async storage package?

Comment: what about for ios?

Comment: I use react-native 0.73.5 and Gradle 8.3. I got this problem after installing async storage. I got also this problem when I install other package like react-native-mmkv-storage or material vector icons.

I don't try on IOS I don't have an Iphone (and don't dl XCode).